# Facing a difficult regular expression issue in cleaning text data

Tags: python, text-mining, data-cleaning, regex

I am trying to substitute a sequence of words with some symbols from a long string appearing in multiple documents. As an example, suppose I want to remove:

```
Decision and analysis and comments
```

from a long string. Let the string be:

```
s = Management's decision and analysis and comments is to be removed.
```

I want to remove `Decision and analysis and comments` from `s`. The catch is, between `Decision`, `and`, `analysis`, `and`, `comments`, in `s` there could be 0, 1 or multiple spaces and newline characters `(\n)` showing up with no pattern in different documents, for example, one document shows:

```
Management's decision  \n \n and analysis\n and \n comments is to be removed
```

while another has a different pattern. How do I account for this and still remove it from the string?

I tried the following, of course unsuccessfully:

```
st = 'Management's decision  \n \n and analysis\n and  \n comments is to be removed'    
re.sub(r'Decision[\s\n]and[\s\n]analysis[\s\n]and[\s\n]comments','',s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove multiple white space matches, you will need `[\s\n]+`, note the inclusion of the `+` (match one or more).

#### Code:

Here is a function which will build the regex automatically from a text snippet:

```
def remove_words(to_clean, words, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    regex = r'[\s\n]+'.join([''] + words.split() + [''])
    return re.sub(regex, ' ', to_clean, flags)
```

#### Test Code:

```
st = "Management's decision  \n \n and analysis\n " \
     "and  \n comments is to be removed"
print(remove_words(st, 'decision and analysis and comments'))
```

#### Results:

```
Management's is to be removed
```